# How to synchronize a GitHub repo with local folder on PC

Tags: git, github

**Hi!**
For a number of reasons, I can't create a repository in one of my local project folders (submodules and sub-trees don't work for me). I would like to compare folder on my PC with the folder on the GitHub server, and if everything is ok - pull without creating a repo in the local folder. Is this possible (maybe a third-party software? Or maybe download each time a repo folder from Github and fetch it with my local folder)?

I think solution to the problem may be in a third-party "folder comparer" on the PC, but I don't know what software would be suitable for it

Comment: Maybe a stupid idea, but cloning the repo where you need it and then deleting all the git related files?

Comment: Can you find somewhere you can clone it, like on your desktop? Then, move the files manually to wherever you need them.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'd like to see the changes in the files, i.e. fetch